# Load more options with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, pagination, swift2

Trying to load my data in page using pagination, I've already seen many examples but all are in Objective-C and some questions are unanswered.

My code:

```
class testTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: - Properties -

    var allObjectArray: NSMutableArray = []
    var elements: NSMutableArray = []

    var currentPage = 0 //number of current page
    var nextpage = 0

    var selectedRow = Int()

    //MARK: - View Life Cycle -

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for var i = 1; i < 500; i++ {
            allObjectArray.addObject(i)
        }
        elements.addObjectsFromArray(allObjectArray.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 30)))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source -

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return elements.count + 1
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedRow = (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
        customCell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        customCell!.textLabel!.text = "cell - \(allObjectArray[indexPath.row])"

        if indexPath.row == elements.count  {
            customCell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            customCell?.textLabel?.text = "Load more..."
        }
        return customCell!
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        nextpage = elements.count

        if indexPath.row == nextpage {
            if indexPath.row == selectedRow {
                currentPage++
                nextpage = elements.count - 5
                elements.addObjectsFromArray(allObjectArray.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(currentPage, 30)))
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want this kind of output:

[image]

Tried to fetch selected index but it will return nil.

Comment: I don't have the time to fully answer the question, but you can download a fully working example of this from https://github.com/Abizern/PartialTable, Uses Xcode7 and Swift 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create Outlets in Interface Builder for tableview and make two dynamic prototype cells give them identifiers make one cell with a button(your load more cell button)
Then create action with that button that will contain the logic to load more cells!!!

now see the snipet below for reference...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tblDemo: UITableView!
var arForCells:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
let simpleCellID = "SimpleCell"
let loadMoreCell = "LoadMoreCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblDemo.delegate = self
    tblDemo.dataSource = self
    arForCells  = NSMutableArray(objects: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arForCells.count + 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.row == arForCells.count){
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(loadMoreCell, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }else {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleCellID, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let lblCounter = cell.viewWithTag(111) as! UILabel
        lblCounter.text = arForCells.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String
        return cell
    }
}

@IBAction func loadMoreCells(sender: AnyObject) {
    let newAr:NSArray = NSArray(objects:  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")

    arForCells.addObjectsFromArray(newAr as [AnyObject])
    tblDemo.reloadData()
}}
```

as I have checked, It should give you the desired results.

You could also do the same in TableViewFooter.

Answer (score 1):

To set "Load More.." text add a label with this text in a view having the same size of your tableViewCell. Then add this in your tableView footer. Add a (custom/transparent)button in footer view so when that touched it will load your main array with more data and then reload your tableView.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You don't have to use this:

```
selectedRow = (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
```

in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. You can use simply

```
selectedRow = indexPath.row
```

next, your logic for willDisplayCellAtIndexPath seems redundant if you want to have cell to tap on it. You can simply put the following in `enter code here`:

```
nextpage = elements.count
if indexPath.row == nextpage {
     currentPage++
     nextpage = elements.count - 5
     elements.addObjectsFromArray(allObjectArray.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(currentPage, 30)))
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

also, I am not sure why do you need `nextpage = elements.count - 5` but I assume that you have reason behind this.

Answer (score 1):

done it my self

```
import UIKit

class LoadMoreTableVC: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: - Properties -

    var allObjectArray: NSMutableArray = []
    var elements: NSMutableArray = []

    var currentPage = 0 //number of current page
    var nextpage = 0

    var totalElements = 500 //total elements
    var elementAtOnePage = 30 //at one page

    //MARK: - View Life Cycle -

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 0 ..< totalElements {
            allObjectArray.addObject(i+1)
        }
        elements.addObjectsFromArray(allObjectArray.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, elementAtOnePage)))
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source -

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let count = elements.count + 1

        if count < allObjectArray.count
        {
            return count
        }
        else
        {
            return allObjectArray.count
        }
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == elements.count {
            loadDataDelayed()
        }
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(allObjectArray[indexPath.row])"
        if indexPath.row == elements.count  {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Load more..."
        }
        return cell
    }
    func loadDataDelayed(){
        currentPage += 1
        elements.addObjectsFromArray(allObjectArray.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(currentPage, elementAtOnePage)))
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: So, basically what I suggested you to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I have already done this is in swift.

```
   func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

      if loading == true {

        var endScrolling:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y +   scrollView.frame.size.height

        if(endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height){

            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "loadDataDelayed", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


        }

    }

}
```

Please try this code.

And share your response.

Happy coding :)

Comment: please provide this code in swift.....I tried to convert in swift but first line self.loading is not working

Comment: Now try and share your words :)

Comment: This will load more results on scroll (when you reach bottom) and OP wanted to have cell for that :)

Comment: @ Shubham Narang your 'loadDataDelayed' method code contains loading data???? but in my code i do for reload in willDisplayCell method

Comment: @GunjaPatel You can add array Objects in 'loadDataDelayed' method and reload the table.
I think this will help you

Comment: @GunjaPatel it was just a bool value

Comment: @ Shubham Narang ..I tried as you told method loadDataDelayed...but it automatically display next array in my case next 30 elements ...not stop for select for "load more"....any soln???

Comment: If you want to select or to stop.
then you will show UIAlertview and ask user to select or stop.