# integrate paging in autocomplete local searching

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm reading json data from file stored in documents directory resulting data array is of count more than 1,30,000.

I've implemented auto-searching method to filter data on the basis of existing data starts with input data i.e prefix predicate and this gets executed on each textfield key event.

As I cannot executes complete loop for each search so i'm breaking my loop for each 12 found result and reload to tableview.
My requirement is how do i achieve paging with so that on scroll next found data gets appended and reloaded.

```
func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(_ substring:     String,textfield:UITextField)
{
    self.autoCompletesCompnies.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    searchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)
    searchQueue!.async
        {

        for comp in self.companies!
        {
            var myString:NSString! = (comp.orgDescription! as NSString).lowercased as NSString!
            myString = myString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) as NSString!
            let searchString = substring.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).lowercased()
            let substringRange :NSRange! = myString.range(of: searchString)

            if (substringRange.location  == 0)
            {
                if !self.autoCompletesCompnies.contains(comp)
                {
                self.autoCompletesCompnies.append(comp)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.sync
                {
                    print("autocompanies count after search ========\(self.autoCompletesCompnies.count)")
                    self.autocompleteTableView.reloadData()
                    //self.autocompleteTableView.isHidden = false 
                    if self.autoCompletesCompnies.count>0
                    {
                        print("is thread suspended \(self.isSuspended)")
                        if !(self.isSuspended!){
                         do {
                          self.tableViewdesignFunc(textfield)
                         }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            self.autocompleteTableView.isHidden = true
                            self.autoCompletesCompnies.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if self.autoCompletesCompnies.count > 12
            {
                break
            }
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: You need to update the data by appending some new values while user scrolling downward. Is I am right?

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy - yes

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let lastElement = dataSource.count - 1
        if indexPath.row == lastElement {
            // handle your logic here to get more items, add it to dataSource and reload tableview
            }    
    }
```

> edit

**Added stack overflow answer.**

Here I got Stack answer by someone, go with it for more specific details [load-more-options-with-uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946909/load-more-options-with-uitableview)